# No command prompt shown while running test in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to fix the problem of no command prompt pop up when i press ctrl+R to run the test? (ctrl+F4 doesnt not work for some reason in my visual studio 2017)
[image]

Comment: Why would you expect running the tests to call `Main`? What happens if you press `F5` instead?

Answer (score 1):

There are not tests in this code. It's a program. You can run it using F5.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Project > [ProgramName]Properties > Application > Output Type: Console Application

This should work if nothing is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, did you set your project as **Startup Project**?

If you did you can either press the play button, which is green arrow on the top, or you can **Press F5** to debug your program.

Be sure you are not running tests and run on **Release** mode.